# Is there a way to integrate this vector expression analytically?

Tags: vector-analysis

We are tasked with determining whether or not $\exists V:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\vec{F}(t)=\vec{r}(t)/|\vec{r}(t)|^3$ satisfies
$$
\vec{F}(t)=-\nabla V
$$
Intuitively I wish to therefore integrate the given expression for $\vec{F}(t)$ with respect to $t$, in hopes of obtaining another expression in terms of $t$, which I may then claim is equal to $-V$. I know that the expression I obtain from integrating $\vec{F}(t)$ must be a scalar, if $\vec{F}(t)$ is to satisfy the given relationship, since $V$ is a scalar function, but since the expression given for $\vec{F}(t)$ is a vector quantity, I'm a little stomped on how to proceed.

Any hints and suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Given the symmetry use spherical coordinates:
$$
F=\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}|^2} \hat{\mathbf r}
$$
so you can integrate and find
$$
F=-\nabla \frac{1}{|\mathbf r|}
$$